# Setting navigationProperty of detached BreezeJS entity to an attached entity adds the parent entity to the manager

Tags: breeze

I am using BreezeJS to model my entity types in an Angular web app. The backend is a custom REST API without metadata. I create detached entities that might or might not have to be persisted, like this:

```
manager.createEntity('ParentType', null, breeze.EntityState.Detached);
```

Setting a navigationProperty of the detached ParentType instance to some entity with a state other than Detached adds the ParentType instance to the manager. Can this behavior be avoided somehow, because I don't care about referential integrity due to the custom backend?

Answer (score 1):

An entity manager is one of the key components of Breeze.  It is used to keep track of all sorts of information such as the entity types that are available and what is in the local entity cache.  By setting it's entityState to detached you are basically creating and then destroying something so I don't see the purpose of why you would want to do this.

A different approach could be to use separate entity managers, one for holding all the types of your entities that are available and then others to actually act as the data stores.  Using this method you could keep your definitions and such clean and empty and only have entities in the other manager.

Good examples of this can be found on this page -

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/multiple-managers

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I might accept it at some point in the future, but for now, I don't believe it totally answers my question. You are probably right in that I don't use BreezeJS in the intended way. However, I feel that the Angular framework is lacking a model/entity perspective and for me, Breeze is filling that purpose better than other alternatives. Thus I would be happy to see BreezeJS evolve into a DB/backend abstraction layer that truly is independent of the underlying server and database and does not - to some degree - expect .NET nor EF.